# How id and name are equals from databse to javafxtableview?

Tags: java, javafx, javafx-tableview

[here is Consing.java](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tF6gB.jpg)[here is my table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MbEMi.jpg)

This is my code.

```
public class TableViewByColumn extends Application{
@Override
public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception {
    ArrayList<Integer> intValues = Consing.getInstance().getBook_ID();
    ArrayList<String> stringValues = Consing.getInstance().getBookName();

    TableView<Integer> table = new TableView<>();
    for(int i=0; i<intValues.size()& i<stringValues.size(); i++){
        table.getItems().add(i);
    }

    TableColumn<Integer,String> stringColunm = new TableColumn<>("Name");
    stringColunm.setCellValueFactory(cellData -> {
        Integer rowIndex = cellData.getValue();
        System.out.println(rowIndex);
        return new ReadOnlyStringWrapper(stringValues.get(rowIndex));
    });

    TableColumn<Integer,Number> intColunm = new TableColumn<>("Value");
    intColunm.setCellValueFactory(cellData -> {
        Integer rowIndex = cellData.getValue();
        return new ReadOnlyIntegerWrapper(intValues.get(rowIndex));
    });
    table.getColumns().add(intColunm);
    table.getColumns().add(stringColunm);
    primaryStage.setScene(new Scene(new BorderPane(table),600,600));
    primaryStage.show();
}
```

[here is my result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WhQLk.jpg)

book_ids and names are not equal as from table.

Comment: show `Consing` code

Comment: Most likely `Consing.getInstance().getBook_ID()` does a new SQL query which returns results by ascending `bookID`, and `Consing.getInstance().getBookName()` also does a new SQL query which returns results by ascending `bookName`.

Comment: I add coad photo

Answer (score -1):

how are you fetching the data from your MySQL database? It looks like you are fetching **bookID** and **bookName** separately, is that correct? If you do that, there is no ordering guarantee so **intValues[0]** does not necessary have to match with **stringValues[0]**.

Comment: This does not answer the question; please ask for clarification by adding a comment to the question itself.